# List items change monitoring when items are instances of class

Tags: enthought

With the following code:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, List, Int, Instance, on_trait_change

class A(HasTraits):
    value = Int(0)

class B(HasTraits):
    lst = List(Instance(A,()))

    @on_trait_change('lst[]')
    def _update(self):
        print('changed')
```

'changed' is printed when the items are changed, as in:

```
b = B(lst = [A()])
```

How to make the event fired when the **internals** of the list items are changed, as in:

```
b.lst[0].value=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to attributes of instances contained in an object using the syntax `container:attribute_name`. See below the decorator on the `_item_update` method:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, List, Int, Instance, on_trait_change

class A(HasTraits):
    value = Int(0)

class B(HasTraits):
    lst = List(Instance(A,()))

    @on_trait_change('lst[]')
    def _update(self):
        print('changed')

    @on_trait_change('lst:value')
    def _item_update(self, name, new):
        print(name, new)

b = B(lst = [A()]) 
b.lst[0].value=1
```

This will print:

```
changed
('value', 1)
```

The "[Semantics](http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/notification.html#semantics)" section of the documentation shows all the possible patterns. The following section, on [Notification Handler Signatures](http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/notification.html#notification-handler-signatures), lists out the possible listener method signatures.